# Absolute referencing in commonjs like system

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I reference all my typescript files like this:

```
import {EntityFactory} from 'src/entities/entity-factory';
```

I really like the absolute path from the root of my project.

This has all worked great.

But now I am trying to move to Webpack.  My Type Script compiler option of `"module": "system"` does not work.  (It compiles fine, but webpack cannot load it.)

So I switched to the supported module loading system: `"module": "commonjs"`

But when I do that, I get errors like this:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/entities/entity-factory'.

If I change it to a relative path then it works:

```
import {EntityFactory} from '../../..src/entities/entity-factory';
```

But I really don't want to do that.  It is harder to read, and to write.  If I must, then I guess I will.

**But before I do, I thought I would ask, is there any way to make `commonjs` work like `system` has been working for me?  (And support absolute paths?)**

Answer (score 0):

> But before I do, I thought I would ask, is there any way to make commonjs work like system has been working for me

Not easily. For it to work the file *needs to be a `node_module`*. The NodeJS world just uses relative paths for *in project* modules. With TypeScript you definitely get a better experience (if the path is wrong you get a compile error).